# Octave: Split a table into subtables after summing rows

Tags: octave

I have a table e.g table(12,4) filled with random numbers from 0 to 1. I want to sum 4 rows of each column of the table mentionned. Then, I would like to store the results in a new table 3x4. After the first 4 results, i try to count the next 4 rows of each column.

To be more clear, here's an example

`0          0.087913    0           0
 0.27561    0.17959     0.24402     0.20616
 0.040698   0           0.056478    0.0039007
 0.10768    0.25992     0.25992     0.25992
 0          0.086466    0           0
 0.27469    0.18798     0.25542     0.21579
 0.04021    0           0.059588    0.0041156
 0.092386   0.22962     0.22962     0.22962
 0          0.087532    0           0
 0.26506    0.18139     0.24646     0.20822
 0.037734   0           0.055918    0.0038621
 0.099674   0.24774     0.24774     0.24774`

Sum of 4 rows for each column for example:

first result is going to be 0+0.27561+0.040698+0.10768.

second result will be 0.087913+0.17959+0+0.2599.

These results will be stored in a table like this

`first result, secondresult, thirdresult, fourthresult
 fifth result, sixthresult, seventhresult, eighthresult
 nineth result, tenthresult, eleventhresult, twelfthresult`

I tried doing this for the first 4 results like this, but I am not quite sure how to do this dynamically for each 4 columns:

```
kkx=zeros(12,4);
kkx=rand(12,4);

[nxx,nyy]=size(kkx);

nxxnew=nxx/4
newtable=zeros(3,4)


for ii=1:nyy
    newtable(1,ii)=sum(kkx(1:4,ii));  
endfor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add a second for-loop which iterates with the step size of 4 in range of the number of rows. Then you just have to add 2 additional variables.

```
rows_ind = 0;
for jj=1:4:nxx
  jj_plus_three = jj + 3;
  rows_ind += 1;
  for ii=1:nyy
      newtable(rows_ind,ii)=sum(kkx(jj:jj_plus_three,ii));  
  endfor
endfor
```

`rows_ind` indicates the row in `newtable` in which the next sums will be written. `jj` and `jj_plus_three` will be the range for the rows that will be summed in column `ii`.